# Why aren't negative diopter glasses invisible?

Tags: refraction, lenses, glass

If the diopters of a set of glasses determine the thickness, and higher diopters determine a thicker glass, why aren't negative diopter glass lens invisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The higher the *magnitude* of the diopter rating the more curved the lens is, and you normally have to make the lens thicker to accommodate that higher curvature (though you can make the lens thinner simply by making it smaller).

The sign of the diopter tells you whether the curvature is concave or convex, and in both cases a high magnitude for the diopter will mean a highly curved lens and therefore a thick lens. The lens is thinnest when the diopter rating is zero, in which case it's just a flat sheet. A zero diopter lens doesn't do anything, so it could indeed be reduced to zero thickness.